# Ruby 1.9.3 Why does "\x03".force_encoding("UTF-8") get \u0003 ,but "\x03".force_encoding("UTF-16") gets "\x03"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, utf-8, utf-16

Ruby 1.9.3

```
irb(main):036:0* "\x03".force_encoding("UTF-16")
=> "\x03"
irb(main):040:0* "\x03".force_encoding("UTF-8")
=> "\u0003"
```

Why is "\x03".force_encoding("UTF-8") is \u0003 and "\x03".force_encoding("UTF-16") ends up with "\x03" , I thought it should be the other way round?

Comment: Please don't just downvote me, do enlighten me if i made wrong assumption. Thanks.

Comment: `"\x03".force_encoding('binary').encode('utf-16')` might be a little more illuminating. `force_encoding` lets you produce invalidly encoded text such as `\x03` pretending to be UTF-16 or `"\xce".force_encoding('utf-8')` pretending to be UTF-8. My UTF-16 knowledge is rather sparse so just a comment.

Comment: Can you explain why i cannot concat "\x81" with [993].pack("n") but i can do it with "\x81" and "\x03\xE1" when [993].pack("n") is "\x03\xE1".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `"\x03"` is not a valid code point in UTF-16, but a valid one in UTF-8 (ASCII 03, ETX, end of text). You have to use at least two bytes to represent a unicode code point in UTF-16.

That's why `"\x03"` can be treated as unicode `\u0003` in UTF-8 but not in UTF-16.

To represent `"\u0003"` in UTF-16, you have to use two byte, either `00 03` or `03 00`, depending on the byte order. That's why we need to specify byte order in UTF-16. For the big-endian version, the byte sequence should be

```
FE FF 00 03
```

For the little-endian, the byte sequence should be

```
FF FE 03 00
```

The byte order mark should appear at the beginning of a string, or at the beginning of a file.

Starting from Ruby 1.9, String is just a byte sequence with a specific encoding as a tag. `force_encoding` is a method to change the encoding tag, it won't affect the byte sequence. You can verify that by inspecting `"\x03".force_encoding("UTF-8").bytes`.

If you see `"\u0003"`, that doesn't mean you got a String which is represented in two bytes `00 03`, but some byte(s) that represents the Unicode code point `0003` **under the specific encoding as carried in that String**. It may be:

```
03              //tagged as UTF-8
FE FF 00 03     //tagged as UTF-16
FF FE 03 00     //tagged as UTF-16
03              //tagged as GBK
03              //tagged as ASCII
00 00 FE FF 00 00 00 03 // tagged as UTF-32
FF FE 00 00 03 00 00 00 // tagged as UTF-32
```

Comment: if "\x03" is not valid in UTF-16, why forcing it to be UTF-16 you get "\x03" instead of "\u0003" ?

Comment: And in case2, clearly \x03 is a one byte thing, and forcing it to be utf-8, i ended up with a 2 bytes thing??? I still don't get it.

Comment: @tensaix2j Starting from Ruby 1.9, String is just a byte sequence with a specific encoding as a tag. `force_encoding` is a method to change the encoding tag, it won't affect the byte sequence. You can validate that by inspecting `"\x03".force_encoding("UTF-8").bytes`.

Comment: "\x81" + [993].pack("n")
    Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings:     IBM437 and ASCII-8BIT
        from (irb):70
        from c:/ruby/2.0.0/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):071:0> [993].pack("n")
=> "\x03\xE1"
irb(main):072:0>
irb(main):073:0* "\x81" + "\x03\xE1"
=> "\x81\x03\xE1"
irb(main):074:0> "\x81" + [993].pack("n").b
Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: IBM437 and ASCII-8BIT
        from (irb):74
        from c:/ruby/2.0.0/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'

Comment: Can you explain why i cannot concat "\x81" with [993].pack("n") but i can do it with "\x81" and "\x03\xE1" when [993].pack("n") is "\x03\xE1"

Comment: @tensaix2j The error message has told you. In your machine, `"\x81"` is `[129]` with a encoding tag `IBM437`, while `[993].pack("n")` gives you `[3, 225]` with a encoding tag `ASCII-8BIT`. You can only concat two String when there underlying encoding tag is the same. In this case, you can do `"\x81".force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT") + [993].pack("n")`